# Could this Beta density related integral be simplified

Tags: integration, analysis, beta-function

I encounter the following integral, where $F^{-1}(u)$ is the quantile function for $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ distribution: for $k \in\mathbb{N}$:

$$\int\limits_{1/2}^1 F^{-1}(u) u^k(1-u)^k\,\mathrm{d}u$$

Could this be simplified to some easier form as a function of $k$? Or if this could not be derived to an explicit form, as $k\rightarrow\infty$, the integrand becoming small, could we say something about its decreasing order in terms of $k$.

Answer (score 1):

**If**
$$F^{-1}(u)=\sqrt{2}\, \text{erf}^{-1}(2 u-1)$$
$$I(k)=\int\limits_{\frac12}^1 F^{-1}(u) u^k(1-u)^k\,du$$ does not show any analytical form.

Computing it and making a quick and dirty linear regression
$$\log\big[I(k)\big]=a+ b\,k$$ for $0 \leq k \leq 50$ gives with $R^2=0.999919$
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval}
   \\
 a & -2.72809 & 0.11301 & \{-2.95532,-2.50086\} \\
 b & -1.44222 & 0.00389 & \{-1.45005,-1.43439\} \\
\end{array}$$

**Edit**

One thing we can try is to let $u=\frac {x+1} 2$ to make
$$I(k)=2^{-2 k-\frac{1}{2}}\int_0^1  \text{erf}^{-1}(x) \left(1-x^2\right)^k\,dx$$ and use the series expansion
$$\text{erf}^{-1}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{c_n}{2 n+1} \Big[\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} x\Big]^{2n+1}$$ where
$$c_0=1 \quad \text{and}\quad c_n=\sum _{m=0}^{n-1} \frac{c_m \,c_{n-m-1}}{(m+1) (2 m+1)}$$
$$I(k)=2^{-2 k-\frac{1}{2}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^{-n-\frac{3}{2}} \pi ^{n+\frac{1}{2}}  \Gamma (2 k+1) \Gamma
   (n+1)}{(2 n+1) \Gamma (2 k+n+2)}c_n$$ Using a few terms, the asymptotics is
$$I(k)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } }{k}\,2^{-2 k-\frac{5}{2}}\exp\Big[-\frac{12-\pi }{12 k} \Big]$$

For $k=5$, this gives $I_5=0.00005280$ while numerical integration gives $0.00005326$.

Comment: How did you get the exponential in the last line?